# Display Frames from .txt file

Tags: code-golf

## The Task:

Given a `.txt` file with frames of ASCII art each separated by a `\n` (see this example if you are unclear) output a motion picture with frame with 1 frame per second.

Note that there is a trailing `\n` on the final frame.

Each frames dimensions will be:

- X<80
- Y<20

## The Rules

- The Previous frame must be cleared before the next is displayed, so just printing each frame onto the terminal isn't a valid answer.
- **New** You can grab the file name however you want, either from it being stored in a variable or from sys args.
- **New** The images must Loop indefinitely
- This is code golf: smallest program wins.

## Example

#### Input

```
0   0
0   0
00000
0   0
0   0

00000
0
00000
0   
00000

0   0
 0 0
  0
  0
  0
```

#### Output

[image: Example Output]

#### Un-golfed

```
import curses, time

stdscr = curses.initscr()

Frames = file.read(file('Frames.txt')).split('\n')
while True:
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(Frames)):
        stdscr.addstr(y,0,Frames[i])
        stdscr.refresh()
        y += 1
        if Frames[i] == '':
            y = 0
            stdscr.clear()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: In languages that don't really support file handling (like JavaScript), is it also OK to put the input in a variable?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I guess you can open the file in a browser and use `document.body.innerText`

Comment: @ProgramFOX Make's it a little unfair, the file handling aspect adds many chars in most languages

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
Import@f~StringSplit~"\n\n"~ListAnimate~1
```

Expects the file name to be stored in variable `f`.

This is the first time Mathematica's precedence rules for `@` and `.~.~.` are exactly the way I need them.

Btw, this snippet could go horribly wrong if the file extension is anything else than `.txt` (because Mathematica will try to guess how to do the import based on that), but luckily that file ending is part of the challenge specification.

Answer (score 6):

### Bash, 82

```sh
IFS=
clear
for((;;)){
while read a;do
[ "$a" ]&&echo $a||(sleep 1;clear)
done<$1
}
```

Assumes the file name of the .txt file is provided as the first argument to the script.

Note that a trailing empty line must be present at the end of the .txt file for this to work.

Special thanks to @professorfish and @DigitalTrauma.

Comment: isn't `$IFS` blank by default? also, use `for ((;;)){ ... }` instead of `while :;do ... done`

Comment: @professorfish IFS by default is <space><tab><newline>. Need to set it to `''` so that `read` can read multiple consecutive spaces, as in the last line of Y

Comment: A couple of small reductions: `IFS=` and `[ "$a" ]` instead of `[ -n "$a" ]`

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>56</s> 55 characters

```ruby
$<.read.split($/*2).cycle{|i|system'cls';$><<i;sleep 1}
```

This program assumes the file name is given as the first argument.

Thanks a lot to Ventero for sharing great improvements!

Un-golfed:

```ruby
$<.read.split($/*2).cycle{ |i|   # read file, split by two newlines, and loop
    system 'cls'   # clear screen
    $><<i   # print the current array item
    sleep 1   # sleep one second
}
```

This program reads the file, splits it into chunks, and prints each chunk separately after clearing the screen. `cls` only works on Windows. A variant with `clear` is 57 characters.

Comment: you can save a character or two, by using a line break instead of the first `;` and omitting the parentheses when calling `split`.

Comment: @m.buettner: Thanks! But why would a line break save characters? Doesn't a line break count as a character?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure what Ruby would do with the semicolon if you omit the parentheses. In general though, I'd rather use line breaks than semicolons as it doesn't make a difference for the character count.

Comment: @m.buettner: I prefer semicolons, because on Windows, a line break can consist of 2 characters: `\r\n`.

Comment: That depends on how you configure your editor. :P I'm using almost exclusively Windows, but my Sublime is configured to use `\n` anyway. Also here on code golf no one will make you add another point to your score for each line break just because you are using Windows. ;)

Comment: `$*` is shorthand for `ARGV`, which would save two characters. In this case, you can save even more by using `ARGF` (or `$<`) though: `a=$<.read.split"\n\n"`. `a.size` is also shorter than `a.length`. And since `sleep` returns its argument after returning, you can combine the last two statements in your loop into `i+=sleep 1`.

Comment: Actually, nevermind the last bit, you can completely eliminate `i` by using `Array#cycle`, which loops forever if no argument is given: `a.cycle{|i|system"cls";$><<i;sleep 1}`. And splitting at `$/+$/` is another character shorter than `"\n\n"`.

Comment: That also allows you to inline the definition of `a`: `$<.read.split($/+$/).cycle{...}` (Sorry about the triple comment, I always think of new improvements right after the comment edit period is over :) )

Comment: @m.buettner: Ah, I see. I used Notepad to write this, and AFAIK, there is no Notepad configuration that can change that.

Comment: @ProgramFOX yes you're probably right

Comment: Whoa you've beating APL with Ruby.

Comment: (not tested) -1 char: replace `$/+$/` with `$/*2`

Comment: @daniero: Thanks, that works!

Comment: Slightly different approach (manually check for the empty line instead of relying on split): `$<.cycle{|i|system"cls"if$_;sleep 1if$_=$/==i;$><<i}`. This version doesn't clear the screen before the first frame, but that seems to be allowed by the rules: "The *previous frame* must be cleared".

Comment: @Ventero: That's shorter indeed, but a different approach, so you can post that as a different answer. Also, I think it is invalid. It doesn't clear the screen before the first frame, but the frame before the first frame is actually the third frame (the "Y" frame), and it doesn't clear that.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Since the approach really isn't that different, I won't post it as a separate answer. Also, I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "the frame before the first frame is actually the third frame". When run, the code first prints the "H", then clears, then prints the "E", clear, "Y", clear, "H", rinse, repeat. So the only missing clear is *before* printing anything at all - which doesn't seem to be required by the rules.

Comment: @Ventero: On my computer, it does not clear the screen after the "Y", and both the "Y" and the "H" appear on the screen.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Ah, I guess your input file has Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`)? This version explicitly compares every line against `$/`, which is `\n` by default.

Comment: @Ventero: Yes, it has `\r\n` line endings, but even after using dos2unix to convert the Windows-style line-endings to Unix-style line endings, I get the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Dyalog APL (64)

(Can't beat Mathematica this time. It seems to have a built-in for everything.)

```
{⎕ML←3⋄{⎕SM←1 1,⍨⊂⊃⍵⊂⍨~⍵∊⎕TC⋄⎕DL 1}¨M⊂⍨~(4/1)⍷⎕TC∊⍨M←80 ¯1⎕MAP⍵}
```

This is a function that takes the filename as its argument. It assumes the file is in Windows (`\r\n`) format.

Explanation:

- `⎕ML←3`: set migration level to 3 (allowing `⊂` to be used as APL2's split feature)
- `M←80 ¯1⎕MAP⍵`: read the file given by the right argument as an ASCII file, and store the contents in `M`.
- `M⊂⍨~(4/1)⍷⎕TC∊⍨M`: find all occurrences of four consecutive terminal control characters, and split `M` on those. This gives each frame.
- `{`...`}¨`: for each of these...

  - `⊂⊃⍵⊂⍨~⍵∊⎕TC`: split the argument (=one frame) on terminal control characters, and then turn the vector-of-vectors into a matrix (so it will display each line on a separate line, this is necessary because `⎕SM` does not understand control characters.)
  - `⎕SM←1 1,⍨`: then display it in the upper left of the `⎕SM` window.
  - `⎕DL 1`: and then wait for one second.

Comment: Ha, finally! And still my answer is not a lot shorter because the function names are just so damn long! :D

Comment: Someone needs to write a Mathematica preprocessor that maps every built in function to a Unicode character

Answer (score 2):

## <s>Awk, 53</s>

```
BEGIN{RS=RS RS}{system("clear")}1;{system("sleep 1")}
```

---

New rules:

## Awk, 74

```
BEGIN{RS=z}{a[NR]=$0}END{while(!system("sleep 1;clear"))print a[i++%NR+1]}
```

Comment: This only loops once, but it can be shortened to `BEGIN{RS=z}{system("sleep 1;clear")}1` ... In awk, `""` is special as `RS` meaning multiline records. To support the new rule of looping indefinitely, I have this so far: `BEGIN{RS=z}END{for(;!system("sleep 1;clear");)print a[i++%NR+1]}{a[NR]=$0}` at 74 characters. gawk supports changing `ARGV` so you can do `BEGIN{RS=z}{system("sleep 1;clear");ARGV[ARGC++]=ARGV[ARGC-1]}1` at 63 characters.

Comment: @laindir: Thanks, I can't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 117

Assumes the file name is stored in variable `f`.

```
import time,os
while 1:
 for i in file.read(file(f)).split('\n'):
  print i
  if i=='':time.sleep(1);os.system('cls')
```

Note: replace `'cls'` with `'clear'` if on a unix based system, adding 2 chrs.

`ctl+C` to quit

Comment: `for i in F: s.addstr(y,0,i); ... if i=='': ...`

Comment: Use `open(f).read()` instead of `file.read(file(f))`, shorter by 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 40

```
seek ARGV,0,!eof;sleep 1;system clear
```

run as

```
perl -p00 frames.pl < animation.txt
```

(i.e. animation file is read through STDIN). 3 bytes for `p00` were added to count. It's 2 characters shorter i.e. **38** on Windows because of `cls` instead of `clear`. Or, to be portable:

```
seek ARGV,0,!eof;sleep 1;system$^O=~/Win/?cls:clear
```

Or, stretching rules a bit (and then 31+3=**34**):

```
seek ARGV,sleep(1)&`reset`,!eof
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol, 74

```
forever[foreach s split to-string read f"^/^/"[call"clear"print s wait 1]]
```

Expects the filename to be stored in variable `f`.   Below is an ungolfed example:

```
f: %ascii-art.txt

forever [
    foreach s split to-string read f "^/^/" [
        call "clear"
        print s
        wait 1
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java, 678 characters(when golfed)**

Of course with GUI, since doing stuff in console sucks with Java, especially if you want to clear the screen ...

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class G extends JFrame
{
    static JTextArea b = new JTextArea();

    G()
    {
        setSize(170, 370);

        add(b);
        b.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, 0, 50));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {   
        new G().setVisible(true);
        new SwingWorker()
        {
            protected Void doInBackground()
            {
                for(;;)
                {
                    try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0])))
                    {
                        String l = null;
                        while(s.hasNextLine())
                        {                           
                            if(l == null  || (l = s.nextLine()).isEmpty())
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                b.setText(l == null ? (l = s.nextLine()) + '\n' : null);
                            }
                            else
                                b.setText(b.getText() + l + '\n');
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception i){}
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just realized there were dimensions in the author's post, but I'm too lazy to change my code now. Won't win anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 163

```
class P
    def main
        while 1
            for i in File.readAllLines("t.txt")
                print i
                if i=="",.x
            .x
    def x
        Threading.Thread.sleep(1000)
        Console.clear
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - <strike>121</strike> 119 chars

Ported [ProgramFOX's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28153/21004) to Groovy 2.2.1. The "clear console" is weak.

***edit***: replaced recursive closure with simple while loop, which is shorter and no stack overflow

```
a=new File(args[0]).text.split "\n\n";i=0;p={println it};while(1){p a[i++%a.size()];Thread.sleep(1000);80.times{p ""}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
a = new File(args[0]).text.split "\n\n"
i = 0

p = { println it }

while(1) {
    p a[i++%a.size()]
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    80.times{p ""}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 81

This is a more groovy way:

```java
new File(args[0]).text.split("\n\n").each{["cls"].execute();print it;sleep(1000)}
```

ungolfed

```java
new File(args[0]).text.split("\n\n").each{
    ["cls"].execute()
    print it
    sleep(1000)
}
```

Comment: The command "cls" doesn't work on my Mac. Also, the requirements suggest that the motion picture loops.

Comment: @Michael Easter `cls` is for Windows I think... try `clear`

Answer (score 0):

## GNU sed, 32

```
1eclear
/^$/{
esleep 1;clear
d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# 226

Why bother eh?

```
namespace System{class P{static void Main(){for(;;)foreach(var x in Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(new IO.StreamReader("f.txt").ReadToEnd(),"\n\r\n")){Console.Clear();Console.WriteLine(x);Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);}}}}
```

**Un-golfed**:

```
namespace System
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for(;;)
            foreach (var x in Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(new IO.StreamReader("f.txt").ReadToEnd(), "\n\r\n"))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(x); 
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or in LINQPAD (so C# can stay semi-competitive with uber shorthand langs :D)

**C# LINQPAD - 134**

```
for(;;)foreach(var x in Regex.Split(new StreamReader("f.txt").ReadToEnd(),"\n\r\n")){x.Dump();Thread.Sleep(1000);Util.ClearResults();}
```

I feel a bit dirty, but hey, this is code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 74 bytes

```
F=LOAD(F)@L
IF" "*!CSRX>F[I]THEN WAIT 60CLS
?F[I];
I=(I+1)MOD LEN(F)GOTO@L
```

F should be the file name